# Splunk prop Config issue

Tags: splunk

I currently writing prop configure to validate my event

Events

```
Feb 03 13:22:23 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 7098.424722] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk Feb 3 13:22:23 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 7098.424725] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 200522427013E6812147 Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710593] usb 2-2.1: Product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710597] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 000650268328
```

Prop.Config Settings

```
[source::linuxusb]
SHOULD_LINEMERGE = true
BREAK_ONLY_BEFORE = Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec
EXTRACT-date = (?i) .*? (?P<date>\w+\s+\d+\s+\d+:\d+:\d+)\s+\w+
EXTRACT-description = (?i) Product: (?P<description>.+?)\s+\w+\s+\d+
EXTRACT-device_mfg = (?i) Manufacturer: (?P<device_mfg>[^ ]+)
EXTRACT-serial_number = (?i) SerialNumber: (?P<serial_number>.+)
```

Result for SerialNumber

```
200522427013E6812147 Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710593] usb 2-2.1: Product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710597] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 000650268328`
```

I only wan 200522427013E6812147. How do i grab this data only. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the events provided are 4 separate events (looking at the timestamps):

```
Feb 03 13:22:23 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 7098.424722] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SanDisk 
Feb 3 13:22:23 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 7098.424725] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 200522427013E6812147 
Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710593] usb 2-2.1: Product: Virtual Bluetooth Adapter 
Feb 4 22:11:46 Jessica-Ubuntu kernel: [ 2.710597] usb 2-2.1: SerialNumber: 000650268328
```

Edit `EXTRACT-serial_number`, changing it to:

`EXTRACT-serial_number = (?i) SerialNumber: (?P<serial_number>[^ ]+)`

Also, if Splunk does not recognize the above 4 events (based on timestamp) as 4 separate events, try changing `SHOULD_LINEMENRGE` to false.